# Глупый вопрос по переменным в SASS Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, scss, bootstrap5

Есть значит в исходнике Bootstrap'а на SCSS такой код:

```
$border-width:                1px;
$border-widths: (
  1: 1px,
  2: 2px,
  3: 3px,
  4: 4px,
  5: 5px
);

$border-color:                $gray-300;
```

`$border-width` и `$border-color` это понятно, самые обычные переменные. А вот как вытащить значние из `$border-widths` что-то не пойму. Вроде бы, и документацию по SASS читал, но ответа на свой вопрос так и не нашёл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это механизм [sass map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map) По сути массив с ключами:

```
.element {
      border-width: map-get($border-widths, 1);
}
```